# Updating a double value, but not higher than x value?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE base_resources
    SET value = value + ?
    WHERE resource_id = ?
    AND base_id = ?
```

I have this query. Is it possible to somehow add a max value for the the value? i.e. The new value of "value" cannot be higher than x, if it is, set it to x.

For example:

If the value entered is (1500) and the max value allowed (that conditional I want to add in my query is) 1000, the value will be 1000 instead.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which sql are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE base_resources
    SET value = least(value + ?, 1500)
    WHERE resource_id = ?
    AND base_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `case` syntax?

```
UPDATE base_resources
    SET value = case 
                  when value + ? > X then X
                  else  value + ?
                end 
    WHERE resource_id = ?
    AND base_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this make business sense? Is `value` the supply of an item in a store? If the store cannot store more than 1500 items, then limiting the value to 1500 might cause a loss of resources.  Imagine a warehouse shipping 500 items to a store. Suppose the store already has 1200 items.  Conceptually, you have this transaction:

- Begin transaction

  - Subtract 500 from the warehouse's stock.
  - Try to add 500 to the store's stock.

    - Only 300 is added.
  - What happens to the extra 200 items? Do they disappear?
- End transaction.

I'm not saying either of the earlier answers are wrong, but I don't know if your situation is meaningful. I would prefer to put a constraint on `value` that it not exceed 1500, and to compute the number of items to send based on the warehouse's stock and the store's capacity.